# System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography Distance with elevation

Tags: c#, geospatial

I'm want to find the distance between 2 points on the planet (using WGS84) and System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography seemed like a good shout, but i'm not getting the expected result from the Distance function when the points have an elevation:

```
var geogA = DbGeography.PointFromText("POINT(179.04 89.77 100)", 4326);
var geogB = DbGeography.PointFromText("POINT(179.04 89.77 200)", 4326);
var distance = geogA.Distance(geogB); //distance is 0, not 100
```

I was expecting distance to be able to take the elevation into account as well - am I missing something obvious here?

I'm sure this must be fairly trivial, but I know little about the maths behind it all, so i'm probably not qualified to make that statement.

My intuition tells me, just use Pythagoras here, but i'm not 100% sure that's correct.

Comment: I wonder if your code would work directly in SQL i.e. STGeomFromText  but it does not work in .NET code.

Comment: Yes, i'll see if I can find a copy of the dll that contains this and see if I get a different result. It would seem, that at least the documentation of the DbGeography is copied directly from the SQLGeography class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SQL Server Libraries Z (Elevation) is more like a Tag or a pure user defined property.

So it is not used in any calculations.    This makes it similar to M which also only has meaning to my specific dataset.

If elevation actually matters to you from a Math perspective then you will have to do this add/minus after you get the geography distance results.   Take care to subtract from the higher elevation.

You are adding two numbers (distance on the surface) + (elevation delta).  If you use Pythagoreans theorem you have to take into account a lot of subtle logic the geography libraries are doing for you.

Comment: Adding the Z difference to the distance won't actually get the shortest distance between the 2 points though, that would measure, down and across (a and b), I want to know c from a Pythagorean point of view. But i'm not convinced that is actually the correct approach. Useful to know that Z is just a "tag" like property and not used in any of the calculations.

Comment: I'll leave it open for another 24-48 hours and then mark this as the answer to "am I missing something obvious here?"

Comment: Maybe your scenario is not best served by the built in "surface of the earth" concepts in the built in geospatial routines.  A real 3 point geometry system is needed in your scenario.   The geometry and geography types are useful but you will just need to do a little extra work.   I would expect at 15 to 30 miles out the curvature of the earth affects "altitude" more than actual altitude such that Pythagoras math becomes misleading to the actual distance.

Comment: Yeah, I really should have opened my post with "Hi, I'm lazy" ha ha! I am already going down the route of learning the maths to write my own implementation.